# .NET Standard NuGet cross platform compatibility

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, .net-standard

I am looking into a way to create a NuGet package that can be consumed by a .NET 4.5.1+ and .NET Core 1.0+ applications. Should I be able to use .NET standard 1.0 framework? Would it matter if this NuGet solution I am building had a dependency on a .NET Core NuGet? Does that make sense?

Comment: I blogged more technical details behind in a post, https://blog.lextudio.com/tips-for-net-nuget-package-authors-august-2017-48f07604e4a0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be able to use .NET standard 1.0 framework?

It might be easier to multi-target; you can use `<TargetFrameworks>net451;netstandard1.0</TargetFrameworks>` or similar to do that in the .csproj; but: .NET 4.5.1 (net451) supports .NET Standard 1.2 and below, so 1.0 should be fine.

> Would it matter if this NuGet solution I am building had a dependency on a .NET Core NuGet?

.NET Core is a framework, not a standard; normally, it is applications (exes) that target .NET Core - libraries target .NET standard.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking into a way to create a NuGet package that can be consumed by a .NET 4.5.1+ and .NET Core 1.0+ applications. Should I be able to use .NET standard 1.0 framework?

Use [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) in order to find out if a particular framework implements some version of .NET Standard.

.Net Framework 4.5.1 implements up to v1.2 so the answer to your question is "yes" - you can use v1.0. However, make sure v1.0 has a sufficient API.

Speaking of @MarcGravell's comment

> It might be easier to multi-target;

I would say **you shouldn't** do that unless you have executable applications rather than shared class library. Always strive to use .NET Standard for a class library project.

> Would it matter if this NuGet solution I am building had a dependency
>   on a .NET Core NuGet? Does that make sense?

There's no need to add any other runtime dependencies once you target .NET Standard or .NET Core. All of those will be added implicitly and will be mentioned within **deps.json** file.